# Calling an Ansible task in a parent role with different values

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I've created two very simple Ansible roles called `base` and `web`. `web` is dependent on `base` and this dependency is defined in `web/meta/main.yml`.

`base` has the following task defined in `base/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: install required packages
  apt:
    name: "{{ install_packages }}"
    update_cache: "{{ apt_update_cache }}"
    cache_valid_time: "{{ apt_cache_valid_time }}"
```

The variables in `base` are defined in `base/defaults/main.yml`:

```
apt_update_cache: yes
apt_cache_valid_time: 3600

install_packages:
  - ufw
  - sshguard
```

The variables in `web` are defined in `web/defaults/main.yml`:

```
install_packages:
 - nginx
```

What I want to do is:

1. Call `install required packages` from `base`, using the `install_packages` variable from `base`, and `apt_update_cache` and `apt_cache_valid_time` from `base`.
2. Call `install required packages` from `web`, using the `install_packages` variable from `web`, and `apt_update_cache` and `apt_cache_valid_time` from `base` (since I haven't overridden either of those two in `web`).

Is this possible, and if so how would I go about doing it? Alternatively, is there a 'better' way to achieve the same result, without reproducing the task in every dependent role (I'm likely to create several others which depend on `base`, and they will all have their own role-specific tasks too)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option.

For clarity, rename `install_packages` in `roles/base/defaults/main.yml` to `base_packages`:

```
---
base_packages:
  - ufw 
  - sshguard
```

Rewrite your package installation task in `roles/base/main.yml` so that it looks like this:

```
---
- name: install required packages
  apt:
    name: "{{ base_packages + extra_packages|default([]) }}"
    update_cache: "{{ apt_update_cache }}"
    cache_valid_time: "{{ apt_cache_valid_time }}"
```

In `roles/web/defaults/main.yml`, define `web_packages`:

```
---
web_packages:
  - nginx
```

And in `roles/web/meta/main.yml`, declare your dependency like this:

```
---
dependencies:
  - role: base
    vars:
      extra_packages: "{{ web_packages }}"
```

If I replace that `apt` task with a `debug` task:

```
- name: install required packages
  debug:
    msg:
      apt:
        name: "{{ base_packages + extra_packages|default([]) }}"
        update_cache: "{{ apt_update_cache }}"
        cache_valid_time: "{{ apt_cache_valid_time }}"
```

And use this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - web
```

I get the following output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [base : install required packages] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "apt": {
            "cache_valid_time": 3600, 
            "name": [
                "ufw", 
                "sshguard", 
                "nginx"
            ], 
            "update_cache": true
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

As you can see, this installs both the packages declared in your `base` role as well as the packages from the `web` role.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will this work if I have multiple roles dependent on `base` though? What happens if I end up creating a role which is dependent on `web`? I'm trying to avoid having parent roles being aware of child roles.